# What is the proper word for "man boobs?"

Tags: word-choice, terminology

Example usages:

> My boyfriend got so fat he now has **man boobs**.
>
> ---
>
> Over-exposure to *xenoestrogen* may give you **man boobs**.

Comment: moobs​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 3):

***Gynecomastia*** is the medical term.

> also *gynaecomastia, gynecomasty*, **"condition of a man having breasts like a woman's,"** 1881, from *gyneco-* "woman, female" + Latinized form of Greek *mazos* "breast," variant of *mastos* (see *masto-*) + abstract noun ending *-ia*.
>
> [[*Etymonline*]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gynecomastia)

Answer (score 2):

These sites refer to it as:

> [***pectoral fat***](http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/lose-pectoral-fat-men-dumbbells-machines-13652.html)

and

> [***chest fat***](http://www.gynecoma.com/workouts-to-lose-chest-fat-men/)

Here, [Gynecoma.com](http://www.gynecoma.com/workouts-to-lose-chest-fat-men/) refers to the difference between *chest fat* and *gynecomastia*:
(TL;DR)

- *gynemcomastia* - breast enlargement due to breast tissue development.
- *chest fat* - enlargement due to fat.

> Gynecomastia in very simple terms is enlargement of the male chest and is caused by excessive growth of breast tissue or gland. [...]  The classification of breast enlargement in men into that which is due to fat and due to breast tissue or gland growth is primarily for the sake of clarity. In reality, things are not that black and white or exactly 100% fat or exactly 100% breast tissue. In the majority of cases of men with breast enlargement, there will always be a combination of fat and breast tissue and this is called mixed gynecomastia. For some, the majority of the mass will be breast tissue and a minority of the mass would be fat or the other way. So in such cases, workouts to lose chest will help to eliminate that part of mass which involves fat.